# css toggle switch status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here is what I have for a toggle switch I'm using off of https://metroui.org.ua/inputs.html
What Im trying to do is change the label thats before the switch/checkbox to say checked or not checked.  If I click on the label it changes the switch but the text does not change.
JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#front_set').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).siblings('label').html('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).siblings('label').html(' not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="front_set">checked</label>
<label class="switch-original right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="front_set">
  <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: @WhiteHat The `for` attribute links a label to an input element that has that id. If you read closely, you can see that the checkbox already has that id. Your suggestion would make the HTML invalid and would cause the label to no longer respond to clicks on behalf of the checkbox.

Comment: Updated my answer with an improved version, that registers the check as a jQuery function, runs it on `window.ready()` and on `change` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue: The label is not a sibling of the clicked checkbox, so you won't find it using `siblings`. The label is actually a sibling of the label that is the parent of the checkbox.

The solution: Use a different selector to find the label, so their relative positions don't matter much anymore. Using `label[for="xyz"]` you can find exactly that label that is bound to checkbox xyz, regardless of its position in the document. This makes your code more flexible too, because it won't break immediately if you reorganize your DOM.

```
var $myLabel = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
$myLabel.html( $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : ' not checked');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#front_set').click(function() {
    var $myLabel = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
    $myLabel.html( $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : ' not checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="front_set">checked</label>
<label class="switch-original right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="front_set">
  <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Your solution is much more flexible.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It looks like this will work nicely for what Im trying to do.

Comment: One question though, Is there a way I can set the status initially? I can set the switch position easily. Im using this to do it: $("#front_set").prop('checked', true);

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You need to change the `parent().siblings('label')`, not `.siblings('label')` because `$(this)` is the element you bind the click event to, which is `$('#front_set')` ( = your input) and that's a child of `<label>`, not a sibling of it. So you need to go up a level, using `.parent()`:</strike>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#front_set').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent().siblings('label').html('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().siblings('label').html(' not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="front_set">checked</label>
<label class="switch-original right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="front_set">
  <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```

What I don't understand is what is that `<span class="check"></span>` doing in your code? It does nothing and your code would do well without it.

---

**Improved version:**

You shouldn't bind events on `click` to checkboxes, but on `change`, as checkboxes can change their value without being clicked. So here is a better version of it, most likely to work on any device, in any browser:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $.fn.extend({
    setLabel: function() {
      var label = $('[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').eq(0);
      $(label).text(($(this).is(':checked') ? '' : 'not ') + 'checked');
    }
  });
  $('#front_set').on('change', function(){
    $(this).setLabel();
  })
  $('#front_set').setLabel();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="front_set">checked</label>
<label class="switch-original right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="front_set">
</label>
```

This also registers the checking of the label as a jQuery function, enabling you to call it on any element using `.setLabel()`. In this version I used [GolezTrol's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712417/1891677) for selecting the label, since it adds flexibility (the parent/child relation between input and label is no longer relevant).